# append dictionary in html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a dictionary with key and list value and i want to create a card using jQuery append function.

```
dict = {
  "Meizu X8": [
    ["4GB 64GB Global", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 12,509"],
    ["4GB 128GB Global", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 13,992"]
  ],
  "Xiaomi Mi8 Lite": [
    ["Global 128GB", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 16,315"]
  ],
  "UMIDIGI F1": [
    ["4GB 128GB", "5 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 10,884"]
  ]
}
```

i want to create a card for every key and if key value having 2 or more list value then function will also create a card with the same key name

for eg-

```
   <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>Meizu X8</div>
     <div class='card-body'>
      <h5>4GB 64GB Global</h5>
       <h5>8 months</h5>
        <h5>8.6</h5>
         <h5>12,509</h5>
     </div>
   </div>

 <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>Meizu X8</div>
     <div class='card-body'>
      <h5>4GB 128GB Global</h5>
       <h5>8 months</h5>
        <h5>8.6</h5>
         <h5>13,992</h5>
     </div>
   </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>Xiaomi Mi8 Lite</div>
     <div class='card-body'>
      <h5>"Global 128GB</h5>
       <h5>8 months</h5>
        <h5>8.6</h5>
         <h5>16,315</h5>
     </div>
   </div>

  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>UMIDIGI F1</div>
     <div class='card-body'>
      <h5>4GB 128GB</h5>
       <h5>5 months</h5>
        <h5>8.6</h5>
         <h5>10,884</h5>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by nesting a for loop inside another for loop, like I've done in the following snippet

```js
var dict = {
  "Meizu X8": [
    ["4GB 64GB Global", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 12,509"],
    ["4GB 128GB Global", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 13,992"]
  ],
  "Xiaomi Mi8 Lite": [
    ["Global 128GB", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 16,315"]
  ],
  "UMIDIGI F1": [
    ["4GB 128GB", "5 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 10,884"]
  ]
}

for (var name in dict) {

  for (var entry of dict[name]) {
    var card = `<div class='card'>
  <div class='card-header'>${name}</div>
  <div class='card-body'>
    <h5>${entry[0]}</h5>
    <h5>${entry[1]}</h5>
    <h5>${entry[2]}</h5>
    <h5>${entry[3]}</h5>
  </div>
</div>`
    $("#container").append(card)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution. It will work even if sometime you will want to expand an array of phone features:

```js
var dict = {
         "Meizu X8": [
             ["4GB 64GB Global", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 12,509"],
             ["4GB 128GB Global", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 13,992"]
         ],
         "Xiaomi Mi8 Lite": [
             ["Global 128GB", "8 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 16,315"]
         ], 
         "UMIDIGI F1": [
             ["4GB 128GB", "5 months ago", "8.6", "\u20b9 10,884"]
         ]
     }
Object.keys(dict).forEach((model) => {
        dict[model].forEach((entry) => {
            var card = `<div class='card'>
                <div class='card-header'>${model}</div>
                <div class='card-body'>`+
                entry.map((feature) => `<h5>${feature}</h5>`).join("") +
                `</div></div>`;
            $("#container").append(card);
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```